# Customer wise sales on month wise using MDX query

Tags: ssas, ssas-2012

I have MDX query fetching last 3 months data based on customer names/previous month sales<>0. Please note to calculate previous month sales, i am using parallelperiod in cube calculation hence I keep [Dim EIS Time].[By Fiscal Year].[Period] along with customername. Executing MDX query getting results in row wise where as looking for month wise sales on column wise.

MDX query::

```
select
{[Measures].[Sales]} on columns,
 Filter((except(
[Dim Customer].[CustomerName].[CustomerName].MEMBERS,
{[Dim Customer].[CustomerName].&[NA],[Dim Customer].[CustomerName].&[UNKNOWN]}),
LastPeriods(3,[Dim Time].[By Fiscal Year].[Period].&[Jul-21])),
abs(round([Measures].[PreviousMonthSales],6))<>0.000000) on rows from [CSIS]
```

Getting results::

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/329uN.png)

Expected results::

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4cgH.png)

Comment: Hi after spending hours found the way to solve my problem. Below code helps to address. Might help for other in future.

Comment: For below filter condition have created named set in cube.

'''
Filter((except(
[Dim Customer].[CustomerName].[CustomerName].MEMBERS,
{[Dim Customer].[CustomerName].&[NA],[Dim Customer].[CustomerName].&[UNKNOWN]})),
abs(round([Measures].[PreviousMonthSales],6))<>0.000000)


SELECT
non empty(LastPeriods(3,[Dim Time].[By Fiscal Year].[Period].&[Jul-21])) on columns,
[Dim Customer].[CustomerName].[CustomerName].MEMBERS
from (
select
Namedset on COLUMNS
from [CSIS]
where ({[Measures].[Sales]},[Dim Time].[By Fiscal Year].[Period].&[Jul-21])
'''